# Filter array of Json Objects using selected checkboxes - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, filter

I am new to react. I have an array of Json Objects and I want to filter this array based on the selected checkboxes. I have multiple checkboxes based on City, Language and Topic. Please refer the screenshot below[image]

Here is my code for the page shown above. How do I implement this functionality? I want that if someone selects a checkbox then data gets filtered and if deselects that then also data gets re-rendered. 
How do I achieve this?

```js
import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';
import SearchPageResultsStyle from "../assets/css/SearchResultsPage.css"
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class SearchResultsPage  extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Printing in the results component: this.props.location.state.data.results")
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data.results)
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.location.state.data.results,
            keyword: this.props.location.state.data.keyword,
            pageOfItems: [],
            city: ''
        };
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update local state with new page of items
        this.setState({pageOfItems});
    }

    handleCityDelhi(event) {
        this.setState({city: event.target.name})

    }
    render() {

        const renderItems = this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3 style={{color: '#1a0dab'}} key={index}>{item.text}</h3>
                    <a href={'https://google.com'} key={index}>{item.tweetUrl}</a>
                    <br/>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>topic: </span>{item.topic}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>city: </span>{item.city}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>lang: </span>{item.lang}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>Hashtags: </span></p>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationBar/>
                <h4 style={{textAlign:'center', color:'#1a0dab'}}>Showing search results for <span style={{fontWeight:'bold', fontStyle:'Italic'}}>'{this.state.keyword}'</span></h4>
                <hr/>
                <div className={'wrap'} style={SearchPageResultsStyle}>
                    <div className={'fleft'}>
                        <h4>Topics</h4>
                        <input name={'Crime'} type={'checkbox'} /> Crime
                        <hr/>
                        <h4>City</h4>
                        <input name={'Delhi'} type={'checkbox'} onChange={this.handleCityDelhi}/> Delhi
                        <hr/>
                        <h4>Language</h4>
                        <input name={'Hindi'} type={'checkbox'}/> Hindi
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'fcenter'}>
                        {renderItems}
                        <Pagination items={this.state.results} onChangePage={this.onChangePage}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'fright'}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SearchResultsPage;
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What about using Array.filter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Andreas It is indeed true that many developers do use JSON objects in day to day life. Thanks, will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state for every checkbox, e.g. topic, city and language and then set state in the handler of each checkbox.Then you can filter the data array to show the filtered data e.g.

```
const { topic, city, language } = this.state;
// assuming data is array and all the filter values are not empty.
// If empty no need for filter
const filteredData = data.filter(val => {
return (topic.length && topic.includes(val.topic)) ||
(city.length && city.includes(val.city)) ||
(language.length && language.includes(val.language))
}
```

Comment: But I will be having 5 cities, 5 Languages and 5 topics checkboxes in total 15 and a user can select any combination of these,for e.g, 2 cities selected, 3 topics selected and 2 languages selected. How Do I implement this?

Comment: You can use array of `topic` in the state and then in the callback function of filter, you can use `topic.includes(val.topic)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes